# Projects Without Makefile

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am trying to build a java game which is a clone of Wolf 3D. The project is in https://github.com/BennyQBD/Wolfenstein3DClone but the issue is the creator did not include a Makefile or else. How do I build and run this project? More importantly how to figure what to do when a project does not include a makefile or build instructions?

I tried doing javac game.java and failed. also I tried open the project in eclipse and see if it will automatically figure what to do and failed. Is it possible that if a project does not have instructions or makefiles, then is a dead project since it will be HARD or Impossible to know what to do in order to make it build and run?

Comment: What did Eclipse do? I would have expected it to compile all of the .java. And the starting class is `MainComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

1. open eclipse, right click on  the project explorer tab and click import
2. open the `General` folder and click on `Projects from Folder or Archive`
3. find the uncompressed folder you downloaded from GitHub and finish.

At this point you have your project properly added to Eclipse, but if you try to run the `MainComponent.java` it will probably return some exceptions.
To solve that you need to download LWJGL, for me it worked with the 2.9.3 so go for that one.
Once you downloaded it and uncompressed it go back to Eclipse and follow these steps:

1. Rigth click on the project's folder and properties
2. Choose Java Build Path on the left and then go to the Libraries tab and expand `JRE System Library`
3. Now select `Native library location`, click on the edit button and go to: `[poath you put your LWJGL folder in]/lwjgl-2.9.3/native/[your OS]`
4. Now click Apply and close and your project is ready to run.

After all this process, when I ran the `MainComponent.java` it compiled and started but it was unplayable but i think that dapends on the source code itsef, not the importing project process.

Hope you good luck with that project.

Comment: although I can now "compiled it" it throws an error for Line 19 in Bitmap.java here: https://github.com/BennyQBD/Wolfenstein3DClone/blob/master/src/com/base/engine/Bitmap.java Apparently it cannot find the image! but the image is there!!! under precisely the place it says it is. Any idea why?